# Where to find high/critical temperatures for GPU?

Tags: central-processing-unit, graphics-processing-unit, cooling

I am looking for a database that has high and critical temperatures listed for CPU's and GPU's, or a tool that will be able to extract this information.

Google is filled with 'my gpu runs at 63C, is it too hot?' and long pointless discussions that talk about their temperatures and setups.

What I am looking for is data that clearly shows at which temperatures various hardware attempts to down-clock itself to cool down and at which temperature it shuts off.

Comment: That should be in the specs or documentation for the hardware in question.  For example, from Intel:  `Does Intel provide temperature ranges for each processor?
Intel does not provide temperature ranges for each processor, as it varies by processor. You can find the thermal specifications for a processor at [Intel® Core™ Processor technical documentation](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/core/CoreTechnicalResources.html).`

Comment: If it's any help, it should be somewhere 65 and 100 Celsius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Intel CPU's, take a look at the T<sub>junction</sub> specification provided at http://ark.intel.com/products/ - in a nutshell, this is the temperature where the processor will take action to reduce it's temperature. This typically means throttling down the cores to the lowest speedstep increment.

There is also the TJ<sub>max</sub> which is the max thermal junction. This is when the CPU will actually shut off from overtemperature. This is not always disclosed - usually it's only disclosed for mobile parts for some reason.